# Plotly Sankey node X Position isn't as expected

Tags: plotly, sankey-diagram

I have a plotly sankey diagram which I'm trying to manually position the nodes.

The node definition look like this :

```
"node" = {
"labels": ["undefined", "undefined category", "utilities", "Asking for information", "transport and highways", "reporting an issue", "street cleaning", "escalated", "Handled by Knowledge", "handled by triage"],
"x": [0.0001, 0.5, 0.0001, 0.5, 0.0001, 0.5, 0.0001, 0.9999, 0.9999, 0.9999]
}
```

I've written it as JSON, however my configuration is actually generated from C# since I'm using the Blazor.Plotly nuget lib.

I've excluded the Y array for brevity.

So... looking at the configuration I would, for example, expect the node with label "Utilities" to have an X position of 0.0001 and yet it's displayed in the center of the screen (horizontally)!

I suspect I misunderstand how the X and Y arrays are supposed to be arranged!

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the y values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... the issue for me in this case was that the label "undefined category" wasn't a target for any source node (my chart was being generated dynamically).

This meant that while the nodes definitions (labels, x and y) were grand,  and links looked sensible, there was a node that wasn't referenced by links!

So, if your nodes aren't where you expect them to be and the X/Y positions align as expected to the labels, make sure all your labels are referenced!

Answer (score 0):

Plotly sankey will overrule your x and y locations if there isn't space for it.  From your diagram, it looks like you're trying to have 3 nodes at x=0.001 flowing into a 4th node at x=0.001, which means that one node would have to pass directly through another node in order to get to its target.  Since that diagram would look like it's flowing into the wrong node, plotly has relocated your offending node to make the diagram rational.  If you have those three source nodes at x=0.001 flowing into a target node at x=0.2, then it should all work.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look here for the syntax:
https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#define-node-position

or for R, here: https://plotly.com/r/sankey-diagram/#define-node-position

Your syntax is off: don't capitalize x, and properly open the list.

```
 node = {
labels = ["undefined", "undefined category", "utilities", "Asking for information", "transport and highways", "reporting an issue", "street cleaning", "escalated", "Handled by Knowledge", "handled by triage"],
"x" = [0.0001, 0.5, 0.0001, 0.5, 0.0001, 0.5, 0.0001, 0.9999, 0.9999, 0.9999]
}
```

I'm surprised that the code didn't return a syntax error.

Comment: There was a typo in the question rather than in the code. I've updated my question

Comment: You didn't enclose the x in quotation marks.

Comment: It doesn't need to be since this is using a Blazor abstraction over plotly as mentioned in my post :)